# Xamarin/Visual studio for Mac: axml file does not appear in intellisense Class file and throw error on build

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

Hi everyone I'm writing a app on Visual studio for Mac/Xamarin with C# and  I'm trying to add my axml file(Layout) named "Dialog_SignUp" into my class to call it but I don't understand why my intellisense does not recognize it and when I try to build it I have an error that said "**Resource layout does not contain a definition of Dialog_SignUp (CS0117)**".

Obviously my file exist and it is on the folder **resource/layout/Dialog_SigbnUP.axml**, so I have done some research on google but I've found nothing on this or I'm not putting the right key words on google.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks.

My Class **DialogSignUp.cs**:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Runtime;

namespace LoginSystem
{
    public class DialogSignUp : DialogFragment
    {
        public DialogSignUp()
        {
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Dialog_SignUp, container, false);

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

My Class **Dialog_SignUp.axml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#DEDEDC"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:minHeight="400dp">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtFirstName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:hint="First Name"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_below="@id/txtFirstName"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtEmail" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
        <Button
            android:text="Sign Up!"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnDialogEmail"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:height="70dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ButtonSignUpStyle"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you I would change filenames in **lowercase with underscores**, like "dialog_signup.axml". In theory both the conventions should be right but I always use the lowercase with underscores.

Second, check that inside your .csproj there is the file inclusion. There should be something like:

```
<AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\dialog_signup.axml" />
```

or

```
<AndroidResource Include="Resources\layout\dialog_signup.axml">
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</AndroidResource>
```

Third, check that in the Resource.designer.cs there is a row like this:

```
public const int dialog_signup = [int];
```

Perhaps you simply need to build again the Resource.designer.cs

Comment: Thanks I'll check that when I'll get home! But I'm pretty sure you're right about this. I didn't think about rebuilding the resource.designer!!!